# Summing and storing specific rows in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

I'm wondering how to sum a specific row, i.e row 2, for all separate matrices in an array.

For example:

```
array1 <- array(1:30, c(2,5,3))
```

I want to get the sum of row 2 only, for each matrix in the array and store it in a matrix.

I've tried variations on:

```
matrix1 <- matrix("", 5,1)
apply(array1[2,,], 1, sum)
matrix1 <- apply(array1[2,,],1,sum]
```

This yields:

```
matrix1
    [1] 36 42 48 54 60
```

Which, is not what I want.

My desired output would be something like:

```
matrix1 
[1] 30,80,130
```

(where 30 = 2+4+6+8+10 , sum of row 2 in the first matrix, 80 = 12 +14 +16+18 +20, sum of row 2 in the second matrix, etc..)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
apply(array1[2,,], MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)
```

To get:

```
[1]  30  80 130
```

The issue with your above example was with the `MARGIN=1` parameter value since you have already subset the array via `[2,,]` to get an intermediate matrix of row values across matrices placed into column form.

e.g.

```
> array1[2,,]

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   12   22
[2,]    4   14   24
[3,]    6   16   26
[4,]    8   18   28
[5,]   10   20   30
```

From there, you need to sum across columns, which requires `MARGIN = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
array1 <- array(1:30, c(2,5,3))
apply(array1,c(3,1),sum)


     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   25   30
[2,]   75   80
[3,]  125  130
```

Here in every matrix, I got the sum of all rows. If you specifically want the sum of second row, then you need only second column